# How to format From/To date in dd/mm/yy using datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, date-format

I found a code snippet [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-DatePicker-Start-Date-should-be-less-than-End-date-validation.aspx), in which it validates that the end date must be greater than the start date, but it uses the format `mm/dd/yy` as below :

```
$("#FromDate").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        var dt = new Date(selected);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
        $("#ToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
    }
  });
$("#ToDate").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        var dt = new Date(selected);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
        $("#FromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
    }
  });
```

Now what it does is that, when the user selects a particular date in the FromDate field say `11/05/2016`, considering the above code with default date format `mm/dd/yy`, it omits all of the date before the date `11/05/2016` in the ToDate Field, or omits the days before `05` (more specifically), and this works wonderful. Now I wanted to change its date format to `dd/mm/yy`, so I added the dateFormat attribute of datepicker as below :

```
$("#FromDate").datepicker({
    .
    dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy'
    .
    .
    }
});
$("#ToDate").datepicker({
    .
    dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy'
    .
    .
    }
});
```

and it worked fine as expected, the date format is now changed to `dd/mm/yy`, now considering the above example, say when the user selects the date `11/05/2016` in the FromDate field, note that now the format has changed and the day is `11` here, now it should omit the days be `11` and not `05`, but it is still taking the `05` part of the date as day and omits before it, now my question is that, how should I modify the above code that it should take the `11` part as day? In other words how do I specify the date format `dd/mm/yy` in datepicker while validating it? I've already specified date format for TextBox Field. Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#FromDate").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function() {
        var minDate = $('#FromDate').datepicker('getDate');
        $("#ToDate").datepicker("change", { minDate: minDate });
    }
});

$("#ToDate").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function() {
        var maxDate = $('#ToDate').datepicker('getDate');
        $("#FromDate").datepicker("change", { maxDate: maxDate });
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much :-)